# CHROME EXTENSION : How to import multiple files in popup.js?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that have a popup.js file. My main problem is that inside the popup.js file there are 6 functions, and I want to separate these function in multiples JS files and import them in popup.js (mostly for maintenance questions)

Require does not work in my case, does anybody know how to do that ?

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "xxx",
    "version": "1.2.7",
    "description": "xxx",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "icons": { "128": "0.png" },

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "storage",
        "contextMenus",
        "background",
        "cookies",
        "notifications",
        "https://www.linkedin.com/*",
        "https://linkedin.com/*"
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>

      <h1 class="ui center aligned header ">
         <span class="highlighted-orange">HubLinked
         </span>
      </h1>


    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Just add them after your include of popup.js. or do you mean dynamically through js code?

Comment: For example,  I have a function test in my popup.js.
I want to move this function into another file : test.js 
And make this function available in popup.js

Comment: Use as many `<script>` tags as you need. Make sure you place them in order taking into account the possible dependencies. Also, put them **inside** the document's `<body>`, in your example it is outside.

Comment: `require` doesn't work in browsers at all, unless you provide a polyfill of this function or build your code with webpack and so on. You can use ES-modules or just add more script tags in html so that all scripts will be running in the common global namespace.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, that's worked !!! Thanks all for your help